# how to passing a argument to this parameter?

Tags: c++

I defined a function at here

```
void PalindromeFinder::truncateToLargestPalindrome(string& inputString)
```

and when I want to test this function I use

```
cout<<truncateToLargestPalindrome("djfklsevesdfjkf")<<endl;
```

then the compiler gave me this error

```
PalindromeFinder.cpp:19:36: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'string'
  (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') cannot
  bind to a value of unrelated type 'const char [8]'
cout<<truncateToLargestPalindrome("racecar")<<endl;
                               ^~~~~~~~~
./PalindromeFinder.h:22:45: note: passing argument to parameter here
void truncateToLargestPalindrome(string&);
```

Comment: The function expects a reference, and probably modifies its argument (since it returns `void`). Use a variable of type `std::string`.

Comment: Does this function modify the `inputString`? If not, why isn't the parameter `const`? If so, how is this invocation supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the result of your function to the `<<` operator, the function has to actually return something. In your current implementation, it returns nothing (`void`), so your code is clearly incorrect.

To make it work, you have to either:

1. return a  `std::string` from your function:

   ```
   string PalindromeFinder::truncateToLargestPalindrome(const string& inputString)
   ```

   ```
   cout << truncateToLargestPalindrome("djfklsevesdfjkf") << endl;
   ```
2. call the function first to modify a local variable, and then stream that variable to `cout`:

   ```
   std::string str = "djfklsevesdfjkf";
   truncateToLargestPalindrome(str);
   cout << str << endl;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a string literal to a non-const `string&` parameter.  The compiler would need to create a temporary `string` object, but a temporary cannot bind to a **non-const lvalue reference**, only to a **const lvalue reference** or an **rvalue reference**.  Thus the compiler error.

You need to change the parameter to be a `const` reference so a temporary `string` can bind to it.  Then you can pass string literals to it.

Also, your function is not returning anything, so you cannot pass it to a streaming `<<` operator (or any other operator, for that matter).

Try this instead:

```
string PalindromeFinder::truncateToLargestPalindrome(const string& inputString)
{
    string outputString = inputString;
    // modify outputString as needed...
    return outputString;
}
```

```
cout << truncateToLargestPalindrome("djfklsevesdfjkf") << endl;
```

Comment: Passing by value is more efficient than passing by reference and then making a copy, because it allows a value to be moved in